# MongoClient creating 22 connections with poolSize set to 1?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connection

I'm having some issues with "too many" connections open to my mongod..

So i started a new database, to make "clean tests", and my poolSize to 1, like this:

```
MongoClient.connect( url, { server:
   { auto_reconnect: true,
     poolSize: 1,
     socketOptions: { keepAlive: 0 } } 
}, function( error, db ) { // save db instance } )

// when the app is terminated i call
db.close()
```

Then i can spot two funny things,

1 - When the app opens, it creates 22 connections to my primary and 24 to my replica.

2 - When i terminate my app there is still 8 to primary remaining and 12 to secondary remaining

Am i doing something wrong?

Any suggestions on how i could purge those "left behind" connections ?

mongod version: v2.6.5

mongodb package version: 1.4.19

EDIT:

Using {} as options yields the same results, so seems like options isn't making any difference.

EDIT2:

Full test code: http://pastebin.com/PSxpHkp3

Comment: Need more code and context! Is it in a loop (or some recursive function)?

Comment: not a loop, neither a recursive function. called 1 time once the app starts.

Comment: Are you forking child processes, or using Cluster; are other node processes lingering after the main process exits? Are you connecting to each node in the replica and having the driver handle it, or a mongos?

Comment: not at all, i'm editing the question to add full test code.

Comment: Where are your numbers on the number of connections coming from? Those are most likely connections for background threads involved in replication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@wdberkeley indeed these were connections from replica and arbitrator...

I wasn't aware those would "Count".

Still i thought my issue was too many connections, but was actually too little RAM ( :

problem solved.

Sorry for accepting my own answer, wish i could just mark your answer "wdberkeley"